# $rootScope is undefined when testing with Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to write some unit tests for an angular project. I've followed some examples about testing a controller but I always end up with the same problem: $rootScope seems to be undefined.

My test.js:

```
describe("Unit: BodyCtrl", function() {

    var scope;

    beforeEach(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    });

    it('foo should be foo', function() {
        expect("foo").toBe("foo");
    });
})
```

and the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$new' of undefined'
```

I have included all the angular files in karma.conf.js. Could it cause problems that I have mounted the main application through sshfs from a server to my local Ubuntu 14.04 and Karma is installed on the said local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject it. Use `inject` in `beforeEach`, otherwise it is a mere variable defined in your function scope which is not defined with any value.

Example:-

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('yourcontroller', {
        $scope: $rootScope.$new()
    });
}));
```